# How to get rid of vertical white lines in a table?

Tags: tables, border, vertical, rowcolor

When coloring rows of my table with a dark color, I get these white vertical lines where borders would normally be. How can I get rid of them?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccccc|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB} 
    \textbf{Segment} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} \\ 
    \hline
    Verfahrensschritt & Start & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Stop \\
    \hline
    \makecell{Abschnittszeit\\ in h:min} & 0 & 36 & 1 & 36 & 120 & 72 & 10 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    \makecell{Dauer insgesamt\\ in h:min} & 0 & 36 & 37 & 73 & 193 & 265 & 275 & 275 \\
    \makecell{Lufttemperatur\\ in C} & 30 & 102,5 & 102,5 & 175 & 175 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\
    \makecell{Autoklavdruck\\ in bar}  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    \makecell{Behältervakuum\\ in bar} & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but shouldn't it be °C  instead of just C? For typesettung units in a uniform way, you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package. Also, I find the unit of the first two  rows quite confusing. The unit you used there is "h:min"  but "72"  seems to be in minutes, following the given unit, it should be 1:12, right? The same also applies to the other times as well, especially: is `1` = 1 minute or 1 hour?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the values in the 3rd and 4th row without changing the unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `makecell` but with a modified `m` type column for the first column, the small white space there disappears:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\widthof{Verfahrensschritt}}|cccccccc|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB} 
    \textbf{Segment} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} \\ 
    \hline
    Verfahrensschritt & Start & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Stop \\
    \hline
    Abschnittszeit \newline in h:min & 0 & 36 & 1 & 36 & 120 & 72 & 10 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB} Dauer insgesamt in h:min & 0 & 36 & 37 & 73 & 193 & 265 & 275 & 275 \\
    Lufttemperatur in C & 30 & 102,5 & 102,5 & 175 & 175 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\
    Autoklavdruck in bar  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    Behältervakuum in bar & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you get rid of all vertical lines and most `\hline` instructions. The mysterious whitespace next to some vertical lines will disappear automatically. Plus, the vertical lines aren't needed anyway.

To improve the legibility of the material in the first column, I'd use left-alignment along with automatic hanging indentation. I would also use math mode in the data columns, in order to enable the use of typographically correct minus symbols instead of text-mode dashes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,vmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{calc,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode, centered
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}m{\widthof{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ L{Verfahrensschritt} *{8}{C} }
    %\hline % <-- not needed
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB} 
    Segment & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
    %\hline % <-- not needed
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    Verfahrensschritt 
    & \mbox{Start}   & \mbox{Betrieb} & \mbox{Betrieb} & \mbox{Betrieb} 
    & \mbox{Betrieb} & \mbox{Betrieb} & \mbox{Betrieb} & \mbox{Stop} \\
    %\hline % <-- not needed
    Abschnittszeit in~h:min & 0 & 36 & 1 & 36 & 120 & 72 & 10 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB} Dauer insgesamt in h:min & 0 & 36 & 37 & 73 & 193 & 265 & 275 & 275 \\
    Lufttemperatur in~\si{\celsius} & 30 & 102{,}5 & 102{,}5 & 175 & 175 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\
    Autoklavdruck  in~bar & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    Behältervakuum in~bar & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 & -0{,}8 \\
    \bottomrule % instead of "\hline"
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution  replaces `\makecell` with `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`. On the other hand, the very thin white lines are an artefact of the pdfviewer (Adobe Reader, for instance, does not show them). I took the opportunity to reduce the interline spacing in the multiline cells of the first column, to have a more readable table.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering\setstackgap{L}{2.2ex}
    \begin{tabular}{|c!{\vrule width 0.4pt}*{8}{c}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    \textbf{Segment} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} \\
    \hline
    Verfahrensschritt & Start & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Stop \\
    \hline
    \Centerstack{Abschnittszeit\\ in h:min} & 0 & 36 & 1 & 36 & 120 & 72 & 10 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    \Centerstack{Dauer insgesamt\\ in h:min} & 0 & 36 & 37 & 73 & 193 & 265 & 275 & 275 \\
    \Centerstack{Lufttemperatur\\ in \si{\celsius}} & 30 & 102,5 & 102,5 & 175 & 175 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\
    \Centerstack{Autoklavdruck\\ in bar} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    \Centerstack{Behältervakuum\\ in bar} & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 & -0,8 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When `\rowcolor` of `colortbl` is used, the row is colored cell by cell (there are as many colored panels as cells in the row).

In such cases, some PDF renderers, such as MuPDF (used for instance in SumatraPDF) or PDF.js used in Firefox), draw thin white lines between the colored panels.

The extension `nicematrix` provide tools to avoid that situation. With the tools of `nicematrix`, there is only one colored panel for each row (and, thus, thin white lines will never appear, whatever PDF viewer is used).

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|m[c]{95pt}|cccccccc|}[color-inside]
    \Hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    \RowStyle{\bfseries} Segment & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
    \Hline
    Verfahrensschritt & Start & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Betrieb & Stop \\
    \Hline
    Abschnittszeit \newline in h:min & 0 & 36 & 1 & 36 & 120 & 72 & 10 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{BBBBBB}
    Dauer insgesamt in h:min & 0 & 36 & 37 & 73 & 193 & 265 & 275 & 275 \\
    Lufttemperatur & 30 & 102.5 & 102.5 & 175 & 175 & 30 & 30 & 30 \\
    Autoklavdruck in bar  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
    Behältervakuum in bar & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ & $-0.8$ \\
    \Hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

We need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]